# I want to limit a SFQ qdisc by bytes

Tags: linux, networking, tc

I have to HTB branches that continue to a SFQ qdisc.

```
tc qdisc add dev eth0 root handle 1: htb default 20
tc class add dev eth0 parent 1: classid 1:1 htb

tc class add dev eth0 parent 1:1 classid 1:10 htb rate 10mbit prio 1
tc class add dev eth0 parent 1:1 classid 1:20 htb rate 10mbit  prio 10

tc qdisc add dev eth0 parent 1:10 classid 1:100 handle 10: sfq pertub 10 flows 1000                                                                                        
tc qdisc add dev eth0 parent 1:20 classid 1:200 handle 20: sfq pertub 10
```

However I want to limit those branches by number of bytes and not packets at the end, so I would want to add a bfifo queue, but as far as I understood I can not add a children to the SFQ since they are classless.

**Edit**

To make it more clear. I want to be able to add a bfifo queue at the end of my hierarchy. But I can not add a new queue after the SFQ.

Comment: Umm, are you talking about [San Francisco Barbecue](http://sfqinfo.blogspot.com/) or [Spring Forest Qigong](http://www.springforestqigong.com/)?  [Holy Trinity Brompton church](https://www.htb.org/about-htb) or [Hampshire Trust Bank](https://www.htb.co.uk/)? We request that people do some research before asking questions here. If you had researched that question, you would have discovered that the “SFQ” and “HTB” acronyms are too obscure to be used without expansion or explanation.

Comment: P.S.  Please do not respond in comments; [edit] your question to make it clearer and more complete.

Comment: If you don't know what SFQ and HTB are in the context of queuing disciplines, then you don't know the answer to the question. All interesting questions are unclear to the uninitiated

Comment: I spent 4 days doing research. And as Bratchley say, I just wrote SFQ (stochastic fair queuing) for simplicity since in the contect of queuing disciplines should be quite clear.